# How to replace " ' " in python?

Tags: python

So I just got a quick question. I need to replace (')    in python but obviously it is not working.

This is the code I use for replaceing things in python:

```
with open('ID.txt','r') as f:
    newlines = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        newlines.append(line.replace('Machine',))
with open('ID.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in newlines:
        f.write(line)
```

Replacing Machine works fine but try out  (')  with the code... it just doesn't work. Can you tell me why? And how can I solve this little problem? ^^

NOTE!: The apostrophe I want to replace does not contain the brackets. I just want to replace the apostrophe :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is in the question: `line.replace("'",)`

Comment: please edit your question to include the code that gives you an error, and also include the error you're seeing.

Comment: Define "obviously", please. I don't see the part of your code that tries to replace that character

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow Link!

Comment: Something unrelated: Don't use `readlines` if you don't have to. `for line in f:` is better code because you don't create an intermediate list that is thrown away after the loop.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that but I solved it right after I asked the question xD

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace(''','')` will run into errors. Try this instead:

`line.replace("'","")`

Answer (score 0):

You can write string literals in python in several ways like

`"bla'bla\"bla"`, `'bla\'bla"bla'`, `"""bla'bla"bla"""`, `'''bla'bla"bla'''`

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in '', "'", '"': print(''' 1'2'3"4"5 '''.replace(a, '*'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very straightforward as it can be handled with replace. There is no "obvious" reason this would not work. There is an "obvious" reason you'd have an error and that is trying to call out a single quot with additional single quotes

```
text = "dog's toy"
text.replace("'","-")
==>"dog-s toy"
```

If you try to use single quotes like this:

```
replace(''')
```

You'd fail for any number of reasons, the most "obvious" being that you've commented out all the following code until the next time you use '''

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
with open('ID.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read().replace("'", "")

with open('ID.txt', 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(contents)
```